# Returning options object for jquery datepicker beforeShow

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to accept a range of date formats in the input field of a jquery ui datepicker by checking them in the beforeShow function.

According to the docs I need to return an options object, however I can't get this to work.

Here is the minimal code to set the datepicker to 01-10-2015 no matter what is entered:

```
<input id="test" name="test" value="" />

$('#test').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    beforeShow: function (input, inst){
        return { setDate: '01-10-2015' }
    }                  
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mp4wbuvm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a comma after the dateFormat property.

```js
$('#test').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
    return {
      setDate: '01-10-2015'
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" name="test" value="" />
```